# Cassandra remote database not retriving data with PHP while retriving with nodejs

Tags: php, database, node.js, cassandra

I am having issue to access data from cassandra database with PHP while I can access with nodejs.

Here is my PHP code

```
$s = "SELECT * FROM user_project_0001 WHERE usermail='sohini.neogi#ATwitslog.com'";
        $stmt = $this->dbf->prepare( $s );
        if( !$stmt ) {
            echo "<br/>\nPDO::errorInfo():<br/>\n";
            print_r($this->dbf->errorInfo());
            echo '<br/>';
        }
        $stmt->execute();
        echo $stmt->rowCount();
        /** Plusieurs projets pour cet utilisateur **/
        if( $stmt->rowCount() > 1 ) {
            echo '<select name="project_name" id="project_name_select">';
            echo '<option value="">' . __( 'Please select', 'weenat-plugin' ) . '</option>';
            while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
                echo '<option value="' . $row['project_name'] . '" ';
                if( isset( $_POST['project_name'] ) && $row['project_name'] == $_POST['project_name'] )
                    echo 'selected="selected"';
                echo '>' . $row['project_name'] . '</option>';
            }
}
```

I am getting 0 records while if I try to access same query with nodejs I am getting 3 records.

Here is nodejs code

```
client.execute("SELECT * FROM user_project_0001 WHERE usermail='sohini.neogi#ATwitslog.com'", function (err, result) {
           if (!err){

               if ( result.rows.length > 0 ) {
                   console.log("Total Records = %d", result.rows.length);
                   var user = result.rows[0];
                   console.log("name = %s", user.usermail);
                   console.log("pname = %s", user.project_name);
               } else {
                   console.log("No results");
               }
           }


       });
```

For PHP I am using PDO to connect

```
$dsn = 'cassandra:host=xx.xxx.xx.xx;port=9160';
$this->dbf = new PDO($dsn);
 $this->dbf->exec("USE senskey01");
```

For nodejs this is my connection with cassandra driver

```
var client = new cassandra.Client({contactPoints: ['xx.xxx.xx.xx'], keyspace: 'senskey01'});
```

I am not getting why PHP is not able to access database.

Comment: Where are you setting the keyspace in php?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an PHP person, but by looking at the instantiation of PDO and also at the query, I think it is missing the keyspace. Try modifying your code to:

1. either connect to a specific keyspace
2. or fully qualify the name of the table in your query:

   ```
   $s = "SELECT * FROM senskey01.user_project_0001 WHERE usermail='sohini.neogi#ATwitslog.com'";
   ```

Comment: no its not working.Also let me tell you I have already used keyspace like this  $this->dbf->exec("USE senskey01");